# ClearCase lsh query filtering

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I was wondering if it is possible to refine the following command prompt query:

> cleartool lsh -all -fmt "%e,%Xn,%Vn,%Nd,%u\n" -since 20090101 > c:\outputfile.csv

I'm looking for a way to restrict my results to 4 users and only for a file extension `*.txt` as the records returned in my `*.cvs` file are simply too many and excel trows a nice error because of the high numbers of rows.

I tried to combine some of the cleartool find commands (`created_by`) but without success.

The current output is fields are:

1. type of operation
2. full path to the file
3. version info
4. timestamp
5. username

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to combine some of the [**`cleartool find`**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) commands, but without success.

Yet, it is the way to filter effectively the set of versions, each one can be then passed to [cleartool lshistory](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lshistory.htm).

Trying to do all in one pass is generally too tricky (`cleartol find xxx -exec "cleartool lshistory %CLEARCASE_XPN%"`), as in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20128451/6309).

It is best to focus on:

- listing the right versions through `cleartool find -fmt "%n %u ..."` in a file, in order to include the name of the user creating the version found.
- filtering that file in order to keep only the requested users, and file types.
- call `cleartool lshistory` for each remaining versions.

Unless '`Vob1`', '`Vob2`' and '`Vob3`' are *all* your vobs (in which case you can do a `cleartool find -avobs`), it is easier to make one `cleartool find` query per vob, appending the results to previously mentioned file.